# Create tables using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, annotations

I tried to create tables using Hibernate with annotations but I don't know where is the problem, I used @Entity as annotations and jta.jar as jars. I downloaded the hibernate and integrated all the .jars include in required.

```
@Entity
public class Utilisateur implements  Serializable
{
@Id
private Integer IdUser;
private String LoginUser;
private String PasswordUser;


public Utilisateur() 
{

}

    LoginUser = loginUser;
    PasswordUser = passwordUser;
}

public String getLoginUser() {
    return LoginUser;
}

public void setLoginUser(String loginUser) {
    LoginUser = loginUser;
}

public String getPasswordUser() {
    return PasswordUser;
}

public void setPasswordUser(String passwordUser) {
    PasswordUser = passwordUser;
}

public String getNomUser() {
    return NomUser;
}

public Integer getIdUser() {
    return IdUser;
}
public void setIdUser(Integer idUser) {
    IdUser = idUser;
}

}
```

In this is hibernate.cfg.xml I added:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> 
    <mapping class="dao.Utilisateur" />
```

Comment: add the code of the class in object, so we can see what's could be wrong

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @cнŝdk I get no error

Comment: @Leviand what should I add?